# Where does homebrew install Drush?

Tags: mac, homebrew

Got Homebrew installed by running:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

After some problem with line endings which I got past I think I installed [Drush](http://www.drush.org/en/master/). After running this command:

```
brew install --HEAD drush
```

And getting these results:

```
Error: No available formula for drush 
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
homebrew/versions/drush4   homebrew/versions/drush5   homebrew/php/drush
my-name--MacBook-Air:~ my-name$
```

I would like to drop my aliases in the Drush folder now.

Comment: I followed Homebrew installation

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in *Searching taps* section, you should run:

```
brew tap homebrew/php/drush
```

Then run the install command as usual.

In the recent Homebrew, installing `drush` should work out-of-box:

```
brew install --HEAD drush
```